# Trash folder not showing files

Tags: nautilus, directory, trash

how the topic says I can't view my Trash folder in nautilus. I have read all tips here for the same bug but any answer was effective for solving my problem. This issue persist since upgrade to precise....I can access the Trash folder when I navigate to the ./local/share/Trash/* but not when I click on Trash icon in nautilus. Folder is accessible from the unity-dash too.
Also root nautilus gives error when trying to access Trash folder: "The folder contents could not be displayed."

**console:**

```
    sudo nautilus
** Message: Initializing gksu extension...
Intializing nautilus-pastebin extension...
Initializing nautilus-dropbox 1.4.0
Initializing nautilus-gdu extension

** (nautilus:10971): CRITICAL **: nautilus_menu_provider_get_background_items: assertion `NAUTILUS_IS_MENU_PROVIDER (provider)' failed
Nautilus-Share-Message: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: 'net usershare' returned error 255: net usershare: cannot open usershare directory /var/lib/samba/usershares. Error No such file or directory
Please ask your system administrator to enable user sharing.


** (nautilus:10971): CRITICAL **: nautilus_menu_provider_get_background_items: assertion `NAUTILUS_IS_MENU_PROVIDER (provider)' failed
sys:1: Warning: /build/buildd/glib2.0-2.32.1/./gobject/gsignal.c:2572: instance `0x1ac0000' has no handler with id `3281'
Shutting down nautilus-gdu extension
```

**xssession-errors:** [**http://www.pasteall.org/31880**](http://www.pasteall.org/31880)

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to ~/.local/share/Trash and change the directory 'files' to another name (e.g '.files'). Then enter the renamed directory (e.g ~/.local/share/Trash/.files), select all the files, and delete them.

Comment: ok. i did it. The folder is accessible now but not in root nautilus. There i can't open Trash:   "The folder contents could not be displayed."

Comment: @user43484: root user can not use Trash feature of Nautilus. This is a long standing Gnome bug, present in Gnome 2.32 too. Not Precise's (or Ubuntu's) fault.

Comment: Ah okay. I can stop to make me worries. Thanks for that clearness.